# Server side response in jQuery datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using server-side processing in jQuery DataTables, but the rows aren't getting added to the table. They are present in the AJAX success, and the rows are also in the data parameter, but they aren't getting added to the table.

```
otable = $('#siteselectiontable').DataTable({
    "serverSide": true,
    "deferLoading": 0,
    "processing": true,
    "paging": true,
    "columns": [{
        "data":"RADIO"
    },
    {
    "data":"SITE_DATA"  
    }
    ],
    "ajax": {
        success: function(data) {
            if(typeof data['error']!="undefined"){
                bootbox.alert({
                    closeButton: false,
                    message: "<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>" +
                        "<strong>Timeout Error: </strong>Please refine your search" +
                        "</div>"
                });
            }
        },
        beforeSend: function() {
            $("#siteselectionfooter").after(progress);
        },
        complete: function() {
            $(".loading-mask").remove();
        }
    },
    "searching": false,
    "ordering": false,
    "lengthChange": false,
    "pageLength": 5,
    "dom": '<"top"><"pull-right"f>t<"bottom center"p><"clear">',
    "fnRowCallback": function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
        $('td:eq(0)', nRow).css({
            'text-align': 'center',
            'vertical-align': 'middle'
        });
    }
});
```

and for the ajax call i am using the below:

```
table.ajax.url(url).load();
```

how can i handle the server side error in a custom way ?
[image]

Comment: have u define the header in jquery datatable?

Comment: where is your datatable code?

Comment: i have define the headers ,rows were also coming ,but sometimes error is also coming which i want to show it my way ,for that i define the "success" but  after adding it rows weren't added to table.

Comment: just add this code --> async: false, in ajax....

Comment: @SmartKiller still the same

Comment: Can you add your sample json from ajax success

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have resolved this with `dataSrc` in ajax options and adding the below line

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.errMode = 'none';    



"ajax": {
        beforeSend: function() {
            $("#siteselectionfooter").after(progress);
        },
        complete: function() {
            $(".loading-mask").remove();
        },
        "dataSrc": function ( json ) {
            if(typeof json['error']!="undefined"){
                bootbox.alert({
                    closeButton: false,
                    message: "<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>" +
                        "<strong>Timeout Error: </strong>Please refine your search" +
                        "</div>"
                });
            }
            return json.data;
         }
    },
```